# Using indices with Box2D?

Tags: box2d

Is there a way to create a polygon with Box2D, by defining Vertices with their Indices?
Since i'm using openGL, I have to define the vertices and indices anyway, and i'm surprised there isn't a way in Box2D to create a body (shape) in the same way i'd normally create a mesh. Am I missing something, or is this normally done differently?

Comment: Why would you need that? Maybe something has changed since I last looked at it, but from what I know (though I might be wrong) Box2D does only support convex shapes. So all you need to do is supply a list of vertices, for which a convex hull will then be created.

Comment: It indeed only supports convex shapes, and my terrain shape is not convex. Therefor I wanted to seperate it in triangles (multiple convex shapes to build the bigger shape).

Comment: Exactly. But all you have to do is pass the vertices of the separated convex shapes. I don't think there is a way to directly generate the multiple convex shapes using an indexed approach. Perhaps someone will prove me wrong, so not an answer but a comment. :)

Comment: If you want to store your vertices to access them later, why don't you store them in the userData of your body ?

Answer (score 0):

In AS3 it could be done with B2D 2.1a version.

```
package org.pf.constructor.shapes
{
import Box2D.Collision.Shapes.b2PolygonShape;
import Box2D.Common.Math.b2Vec2;

/**
 * ...
 * @author zeksa'
 */
public class PFb2dConvexShape extends b2PolygonShape
{
    private var _vertices:Array = new Array();

    public function PFb2dConvexShape(vertices:Array)
    {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < vertices.length; i++)
        {
            _vertices.push(new b2Vec2(vertices[i][0] / 30, vertices[i][1] / 30));
        }
        SetAsArray(_vertices, _vertices.length);
    }

}

}
```

I've done that in this way. Think you can make the same on C++.
Box2D supports only convex shapes. If you want concave shapes, I think [this article](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2011/09/12/create-non-convex-complex-shapes-with-box2d/) will help you, AS3 only =). Hope you will catch idea how to do this on C++.
Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the poly2tri library : http://code.google.com/p/poly2tri/

It's a very quick an efficient lib to perform Constrained Delaunay Triangulation (http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation). 
It outputs a map of triangles from your input vertices (and eventually Steiner points, but you'll have to compute them by yourself to have a refined Delaunay, or use the C version of the lib), then you can build your fixtures with them.

That's what I did here : http://vimeo.com/m/33500649

Be careful that the lib will not accept self-intersecting polygons, duplicate points or colinear points. You'll have to check for this before computing the triangulation.

If you're used to the glib library, I guess you should try to implement the C version, but I didn't try it myself, so I can't tell. I think it's even faster than the C++ one, and it does implement refining. Can be useful for a mesh.